# How to fill html table with AngularJS from Java's JSONArray?

Tags: java, html, angularjs, json, servlets

I'm trying to send a json array from my java servlet (using mysql server) to html page using JSONObject and JSONArray. The array is sent successfully to html page but the table itself is not getting anything.

It is what I always get on first line of html page and the table itself is not getting anything.

```
{"Info":[{"Name":"Jack","Lastname":"Nilson","Birthday":"1980-10-10","Address":"Nowhere","State": "ABC","ZIP":"999"}]}
```

**Servlet** (doPost)

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select* from db");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray();
        while(rs.next()){
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("Name", rs.getString(1));
            obj.put("Lastname", rs.getString(2));
            obj.put("Birthday", rs.getDate(3));
            obj.put("Address", rs.getString(4));
            obj.put("State", rs.getString(5));
            obj.put("ZIP", rs.getInt(6));
            jarr.put(obj);
        }
        JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject();
        json1.put("Info", jarr);

        response.getWriter().write(json1.toString());
        rs.close();
```

**AngularJS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.post("InfoServletPath")
    .then(function (response) {
       $scope.Info = response.data.Info;
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
    <body>
   <form action="InfoServletPath" method="POST">
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
                <table id="pInfo">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="10%">Name</th>
                            <th width="10%">Lastname</th>
                            <th width="10%">Birthday</th>
                            <th width="10%">Address</th>
                            <th width="10%">STATE</th>
                            <th width="10%">Zip</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tr ng-repeat="row in Info">
                        <td> {{ row.Name }} </td>
                        <td> {{ row.Lastname }} </td>
                        <td> {{ row.Birthday }} </td>
                        <td> {{ row.Address }} </td>
                        <td> {{ row.State }} </td>
                        <td> {{ row.ZIP }} </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

I've had this problem for days and quite honestly I can't seem to find any solution to the problem. The only thing I found on the internet and in stackoverflow was about how to fill a table with AngularJS from a json file. I may have the problem setting up my angularJS script code but I don't really know how to do it in this very situation. Any help towards this issue is much appreciated!

OBS that I do not use JSP.

Comment: can you share the output from `console.log(response)` and `console.log(response.data)` inside your promise/response ?

Comment: @Searching 'Invalid json response' is what I get

Comment: @Searching I'm pretty sure the problem might be with my angularjs code but I'm not entirely sure where the issue is. Hmm

Comment: did you check the browser dev tools Network tab to see if the data u send from ur jsp is properly formatted? Your error is saying it isn't. Sorry typing from phone..

Comment: I just checked and you were right. It doesn't show. But why does it throw it to webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your last comment it seems that you are missing `content-type : application/json` when writing back your response. You angular setup looks just fine. No issues there...

```
JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject();
json1.put("Info", jarr);

response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

response.getWriter().write(json1.toString());
rs.close();
```

Comment: I've it in very beginning of the doPost function. response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");

Comment: Hmm..give this a shot instead and see if the console.log still outputs the same error?

Comment: Send an empty json object without filling data to see if there is a formatting issue may be. Are you getting the same error even after setting them separately ?

Comment: wait why do you $.post instead of $.get ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129605/discussion-between-searching-and-v-g).